# Late implementation of an interface

Tags: c++, interface

I have a class Foo.

```
struct Foo
{
    void someFunc()
    {
    }
};
```

I have an interface IFoo.

```
struct IFoo
{
    virtual void someFunc() = 0;
};
```

If I didn't want to implement IFoo into Foo directly, is there a way to do it at a later point?

...

A FAILED attempt was to do this:
Create a class which implements them both... THEORETICALLY satisfying IFoo by also inheriting from Foo.

```
struct Bar : Foo, IFoo
{

};
```

Which could be used like this:

```
Bar x = Bar();
IFoo* y = &x;
```

But that didn't work. The compiler sees Bar as abstract.

Does anyone have any ideas please? There is no actual code problem to paste, I am just trying to see if something like this would be possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? Or was this more like a theoretical question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct Bar : IFoo, Foo
{
    virtual void someFunc()
    {
        Foo::someFunc();
    }
};
```

or:

```
struct Bar : IFoo
{
    Foo foo;    
    virtual void someFunc()
    {
        foo.someFunc();
    }
};
```

Comment: We have a winner. I knew it would be simple! Thanks bud. It seems so obvious now :-/

Comment: What sort of struct would Bar be? A wrapper? If I were to give it a name relating to Foo, what would you call it? FooWrapper?

Comment: What I mean is... what design pattern would this be categorised under?

Comment: @Beakie: don't know the name for the first one involving multiple inheritance, but the second one can be adapter

Comment: @Beakie the two solutions are both implementation of the design pattern "Adapter" (AKA "wrapper")

Comment: @PiotrS. The multiple inheritance bit could be called mixin, no?